# Extract translation from scale matrix

Tags: matrix, opengl-es-2.0, translation, scaling

Hi I am beginner to open gles 2.0. And I am working on android platform.

So till now I did few things like rendering object and scaling and translations.

My question is more related to matrix operations, my scenario is like this:

I have two object in open gl surface. I already implemented scale and translation.

Now what I want to do when user tried to scale object then apply scaling on one object but not on second one.

Instead of that move that object to appropriate position according to scale.

So I want to extract translation from scale matrix and apply it on second object so that it will take position according to scale.

Need help. Thank you.

Comment: This feels so straightforward that I think there is something I miss but anyway: Scaling is done on the diagonal axis, so extract those values and send them to your translation matrix. Then use the translated matrix on your second cube. You have setup your model, view and projection matrices, right?

Comment: yeah.So I took values from scale matrix that diagonal values and form my translate matrix but its not working properly. I think I an doing some thing wrong on my math side. scaling cause multiplication by scale factor and translate cause addition. So may be I have to dig more in that. By the way thank you for help. Thankx a lot.

Comment: You can always check your matrices, translation and scaling is fairly straightforward to observe.

Comment: yeah that's true.I am trying to figure it out. If you have any idea please let me know also :)

Comment: First, make sure your matrices are correct. Second, make sure they are bound to your shader correctly, maybe check some value in your shader. Not to forget that the issue might be related to column major and row major differences too. Since scaling is done in diagonal axis, row major and column major does not make a difference. But in translation, it does matter.

Comment: I did it in different way. I have center point for object. we know scaling mean multiplying all coordinates by scale factor. mean if scale factor is 2; it will scale that object by 2 units. So for my scenario i shift my origin by scale factor. Now for zoom event my one object scale by 2 (scale factor) and another object will shift according to that . :) it works fine. By still like to know conversion of scale to translation if any one knows it. Thank you.

Comment: So you edit your vertex coordinates instead of using model, view, projection matrices in your shader?

Comment: yeah.I am using model view projection matrices but only for this scenario where I want to scale one object and translate another object in amount amount I am doing this thing. Is there any better way sir ?

Comment: The better way is using model, view and projection matrices, as you know that's the convention in OpenGL.

Comment: yeah that's true. I will try in that way and let you know if possible. :)